# jQuery/c# - how to tell if acrobat plugin is installed and web viewer setting is true?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, adobe-reader

In jQuery or c# (since I am working on an .aspx page on Sharepoint 2010) is there a way to detect if the acrobat plugin is installed and the web viewer setting is enabled. I believe the plugin gets installed with adobe reader 10 and above. I have this

```
$.each(navigator.plugins, function() {
    if (this.name == "Adobe Acrobat") {
        $('body').append("You have Acrobat");           
    }
});
```

but I am not sure if this is good enough.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Edit: This needs to work with at least IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin would be of use to you:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqplugin

And not jquery plugin how still JS:

http://thecodeabode.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/detect-adobe-reader-plugin.html

Comment: Thanks, so this plugin will I guess detect if the plugin is there, but how can I detect if the web viewer setting is enabled. I know to enable/disable it, you have to go into preferences in adobe reader application.

Comment: You cannot detect that setting as it is an Acrobat setting, and nothing to do with the browser.